Blind man owns old house in French countryside, befriends neighbours, house burns down
Foreign film, French I think. Blind man owns old house in french countryside (with wife?). Befriends neighbours and knows his way home in the dark by feel. House burns down one night while they were at the neighbours' house. Neighbours take him in, he ends up sleeping with the wife of his neighbour.
Saw it on TV about 5 years ago. I though it had a common English name like 'the country house' or something but not sure. No actors that I knew. Old stone french house; I think they were artists. The blind man walks to the neighbours' house through the countryside, knows where the trees etc. are by feel. It's a younger couple and the neighbours get seduced into wife swapping by the older blind man.

Approximate year of release? Genre? Where did you see it? Did you recognize any of the actors? (Pretty sure I know what you're after, but this would really help.)

sorry, not much detail only vaguely remember it myself. Saw it on TV about 5 years ago. I though it had a common english name like 'the country house' or something but not sure. No actors that i knew. Old stone french house, i think they were artists. he walks to the neighbours house through the countryside, I knows where the trees etc are by feel. the house burnt down one night while they were at the neighbours house...

younger couple neighbours get seduced into wife swap by older blind man...

Sounds like Peindre ou faire l'amour (To Paint or Make Love) (2005), but the blind man is younger.

An affluent, middle-aged couple's uneventful lives are forever changed when they move into an isolated house in the country and befriend an odd, younger couple.

The young man in that couple is blind. When their house burns down, they move in with their friendly, older neighbours and eventually begin to have an affair with them, swinger-style. Here's the trailer:




thats it cheers! thanks guys!
